# How to align or center the bars of a histogram on the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
qplot(carat,data=diamonds,geom="histogram",binwidth=1,xlim=c(0,3))
```

I use this code to draw a histogram. But the result is different from that of book.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe use the `center` argument - `qplot(carat,data=diamonds,geom="histogram",binwidth=1,xlim=c(0,3), center = 0.5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities, either use the `center` parameter as [suggested by Richard Telford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229652/r-ggplots-my-histograms-x-axis-is-wrong#comment75470062_44229652) or the `boundary` parameter.

Both codes below will create the same chart:

```
library(ggplot2)  # CRAN version 2.2.1 used
qplot(carat, data=diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 1, xlim = c(0,3),
      center = 0.5)
qplot(carat, data=diamonds, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 1, xlim = c(0,3),
      boundary = 0)
```

[image]

For more details, please, see `?geom_histogram`.