# Align bars and ticks with geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

My question is related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453008/4375580) by stibu. I am using `geom_bar` and I am trying to center the bars between the x-axis ticks (see the second graph of the answer).

Here is an example:

```
grp<-letters[1:13]
count<-c(38,591,549,487,419,363,276,276,164,68,31,10,5)
data<-data.frame(grp,count)
ggplot(data,aes(x=grp,y=count))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

- My x axis is made of character variables so I can not use the "+0,5" trick.
- There is no `boundary` or `center` option for geom_bar as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44235989)

So how do I align bars so that their left border is aligned with the tick?

I am using R version 3.4.0 and RStudio 1.0.143.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
require(ggplot2)

grp<-letters[1:13]
count<-c(38,591,549,487,419,363,276,276,164,68,31,10,5)
data<-data.frame(grp,count)
ggplot(data,aes(x=grp,y=count))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",  
           width = 0.9, 
           position = position_nudge(x = 0.5))
```